# No Java support on firefox

Tags: java, firefox, npapi

Hey so I have this IP printer that uses some java-applet to get it's work done, yet as of a few days ago, firefox dropped all support for npapi plugins but flash, hence java is no longer supported.... They have claimed to release some new distribution that would have extended support for java users... yet apparently this doesn't work for me.... any idea how to solve this and allow java support by my browser?

Comment: Applets are dead; if you must use it for some reason - you'll probably have to run it with the standalone [applet viewer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/appletviewer.html).

Comment: You need FireFox 52, Extended Service Release version

Answer (score 2):

There's no hope for applets in the long run.
As for Firefox 52, [you can add **plugin.load_flash_only:false** in about:config](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/03/force-enable-firefox-52-npapi-support).
Or you can install [Firefox ESR 52](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/faq/) to postpone the problem a bit longer.

Answer (score -3):

Firefox

Open the Firefox browser or restart it, if it is already running

From the Firefox menu, select Tools, then click the Add-ons option

In the Add-ons Manager window, select Plugins

Click Java (TM) Platform plugin (Windows) or Java Applet Plug-in (Mac OS X) to select it

Check that the option selected is Ask to Activate or Always

Activate or on older Firefox versions, click on the Enable button (if the button says Disable, Java is already enabled)

Comment: nope. I dont have such plugin on add-ons manager, please read more about npapi dropping support